# Custom discrete color scale in ggplot does not respect order

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

## Context

I'm trying to create a custom color scale to be called using something like `scale_fill_perso` in `ggplot`. I followed the steps described in this nice [blog post](https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/creating-corporate-colour-palettes-for-ggplot2). My discrete scale has 7 levels.

I managed to set the scale correctly (see below). When using a graph with 7 levels, I have the expected colors. However, when I don't use as many colors, I would like `R` to respect the order of my palette and not interpolate between values (see example). For instance, if I have 3 colors, I would like `R` to use the first three values of my color vector.

I think this comes from `my_pal` that itself uses `grDevices::colorRampPalette` which, when using a number of classes smaller than the size of the color vector, cuts the color vector using extremes rather than order.

So my question is: **Is there some way to capture the number of classes and, if `number classes < length(color vector)` do not use `colorRampPalette` interpolation ?**

## Current implementation

Steps follow the aforementioned [blog post](https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/creating-corporate-colour-palettes-for-ggplot2).

First, create a color vector and a way to call it:

```r
mycolors <- c(
`red` = "#E2447A",
`green` = "#BCE550",
`blue` = "#708DD3", 
`grey` = "#666666",
`orange` = "#FFBAA8",
`violet` = "#D1A3FF",
`lightgrey` = "#B2B2B2"
)

my_cols <- function(...) {

  cols <- c(...)

  if (is.null(cols))
    return (mycolors)

  mycolors[cols]
}

call_palettes <- function(palette = "main"){
  if (palette == "main"){ return(my_cols()) }
}
```

There's only one palette for the moment but this might change. Then create the palette function that interpolates values (for what I understood):

```r
my_pal <- function(palette = "main", reverse = FALSE, ...) {

  args <- list(...)
  #return(args)

  pal <- call_palettes(palette, ...)

  if (reverse) pal <- rev(pal)

  grDevices::colorRampPalette(pal, ...)
}
```

Then create `scale_fill_perso` function to use that palette.

```r
scale_fill_perso <- function(palette = "main", discrete = TRUE, reverse = FALSE, ...) {
  pal <- my_pal(palette = palette, reverse = reverse)

  if (discrete) {
    ggplot2::discrete_scale("fill", paste0("my_pal_", palette), palette = pal, ...)
  } else {
    ggplot2::scale_fill_gradientn(colours = pal(256), ...)
  }
}
```

## Output

Using 7 classes, no problem:

```r
iris$random <- sample(1:7, nrow(iris), replace = TRUE)

ggplot2::ggplot(iris) +
  ggplot2::geom_histogram(ggplot2::aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = ..density..,
                                       fill = factor(random))) +
  scale_fill_perso(palette = "main")
```

[image]

However, when using a number of colors smaller, I would like to use the first three colors of my vector (red-green-blue), which is not the case for the moment

```r
ggplot2::ggplot(iris) +
  ggplot2::geom_histogram(ggplot2::aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = ..density..,
                                       fill = factor(Species))) +
  scale_fill_perso(palette = "main")
```

[image]

I identified that comes from the fact that `my_pal` is not taking order of the vector as informative. For instance, for 2 colors, it takes the two extremes of the vector:

```r
my_pal()(2)
# "#E2447A" "#B2B2B2"
mycolors 
#      red     green      blue      grey    orange    violet lightgrey 
# "#E2447A" "#BCE550" "#708DD3" "#666666" "#FFBAA8" "#D1A3FF" "#B2B2B2"
```

and for three, it adds the middle value:

```r
my_pal()(3)
# "#E2447A" "#666666" "#B2B2B2"
mycolors 
#      red     green      blue      grey    orange    violet lightgrey 
# "#E2447A" "#BCE550" "#708DD3" "#666666" "#FFBAA8" "#D1A3FF" "#B2B2B2"
```

How can I ensure to follow vector order when number classes < number colors ?

Comment: it's the `grDevices::colorRampPalette(pal, ...)`. Check `ggpubr::get_palette()` for ideas to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, did not knew about `ggpubr` package. The solution I found is to modify slightly the `colorRampPalette` when the number of classes < number of colors

Answer (score 1):

After digging a little bit, I found a solution by modifying slightly the `colorRamp` and `colorRampPalette` functions.

The idea is to capture the number of classes within `colorRampPalette` and use it as an argument to slice color vector in `colorRamp` function:

```r
colorRamp_d <- function (colors, n,
                         bias = 1,
                         space = c("rgb", "Lab"),
                         interpolate = c("linear",
                                         "spline"),
                         alpha = FALSE){

  # PRELIMINARY STEPS ----------------
  if (bias <= 0)
    stop("'bias' must be positive")
  if (!missing(space) && alpha)
    stop("'alpha' must be false if 'space' is specified")
  colors <- t(col2rgb(colors, alpha = alpha)/255)
  space <- match.arg(space)
  interpolate <- match.arg(interpolate)

  # CUT THE COLOR VECTOR ----------------------

  if (space == "Lab")
    colors <- convertColor(colors, from = "sRGB", to = "Lab")
  interpolate <- switch(interpolate, linear = stats::approxfun,
                        spline = stats::splinefun)

  # RESPECT ORDER IF NCLASSES<NCOLORS
  if (n<nrow(colors)) colors <- colors[1:n,]

  if ((nc <- nrow(colors)) == 1L) {
    colors <- colors[c(1L, 1L), ]
    nc <- 2L
  }
  x <- seq.int(0, 1, length.out = nc)^bias
  palette <- c(interpolate(x, colors[, 1L]), interpolate(x,
                                                         colors[, 2L]), interpolate(x, colors[, 3L]), if (alpha) interpolate(x,
                                                                                                                             colors[, 4L]))
  roundcolor <- function(rgb) pmax(pmin(rgb, 1), 0)
  if (space == "Lab")
    function(x) roundcolor(convertColor(cbind(palette[[1L]](x),
                                              palette[[2L]](x), palette[[3L]](x), if (alpha)
                                                palette[[4L]](x)), from = "Lab", to = "sRGB")) *
    255
  else function(x) roundcolor(cbind(palette[[1L]](x), palette[[2L]](x),
                                    palette[[3L]](x), if (alpha)
                                      palette[[4L]](x))) * 255
}


colorRampPalette_d <- function (colors, ...){
  # n: number of classes
  function(n) {
    ramp <- colorRamp_d(colors, n, ...)
    x <- ramp(seq.int(0, 1, length.out = n))
    if (ncol(x) == 4L)
      rgb(x[, 1L], x[, 2L], x[, 3L], x[, 4L], maxColorValue = 255)
    else rgb(x[, 1L], x[, 2L], x[, 3L], maxColorValue = 255)
  }
}
```

The only difference with `grDevices::colorRamp` function is the argument `n` (number of classes) and the slicing introduced by this line :

```r
if (n<nrow(colors)) colors <- colors[1:n,]
```

Finally, instead of calling `Grdevices::colorRampPalette`, I call my custom `colorRampPalette_d`:

```r
my_pal <- function(palette = "main", reverse = FALSE, ...) {

  args <- list(...)
  #return(args)

  pal <- call_palettes(palette, ...)

  if (reverse) pal <- rev(pal)

  colorRampPalette_d(pal, ...)
}
```

Which yields:

```r
ggplot2::ggplot(iris) +
  ggplot2::geom_histogram(ggplot2::aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = ..density..,
                                       fill = factor(Species))) +
  scale_fill_perso(palette = "main")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

linog's answer to the question solved my problem. I can't comment on the answer but for anyone else using it, note that you have to modify two functions, `colorRamp` and `colorRampPalette`, in the latter the call to `colorRamp` is moved within the subfunction from just before it, becoming `ramp <- colorRamp_d(colors, n, ...)`.

Another approach to a custom color scale can be found here, https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/custom-discrete-color-scales-for-ggplot2/, but this takes an alternative approach and doesn't use the `colorRamp` functionality so can only be used for discrete scales with a maximum number of colors. It does allow for default colors so may suit analysis where just getting a quick set of charts with a limited color range out. It also shows how to cater for both British and American spelling of colour.